# Trouble plugging Aptana into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aptana

I'm trying to add Aptana to my Eclipse installation. I'm trying to do so on Win7 x64. I've tried both x86 and x64 versions of Eclipse. Most of the time Eclipse would install just fine, run okay, but as soon as I try to pluin Aptana it has problems. It will start up, then encounter an error immediately and close. Right now I have the x64 version installed fine. When I start it up it throws the error but doesn't close. I can close the error window and continue using Aptana just fine. I've attached a couple screenshots to show what the error is and what my current Installation Details look like. Let me know if there's any other information I could provide.

Thanks in advance.

Aaron-

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the 'Error log' view, you probably see the stack of the NPE.
Then try to google the solution.

Comment: I'm so glad you told me how to do this. It's helped tremendously now!